# Merging by array value (and doing calculations with the other keys)

Tags: php, arrays, merge, grouping

I'm having a difficult time finding a viable solution for this problem:

This is the array I have, and I want to group this array by `product_name` and count the quantity. But array structure needs to remain the same.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => Appel
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => D-Day
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 4
        [product_name] => D-Day
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 2
        [product_name] => D-Day
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => Emiel
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 9
        [product_name] => Emiel
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 3
        [product_name] => Estella
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 4
        [product_name] => Feeke
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => Feeke
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 7
        [product_name] => Reset
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [product_quantity] => 1
        [product_name] => Reset
    ))
```

What I need as output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_quantity] => 1
            [product_name] => Appel
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_quantity] => 7
            [product_name] => D-Day
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_quantity] => 10
            [product_name] => Emiel
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_quantity] => 3
            [product_name] => Estella
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_quantity] => 5
            [product_name] => Feeke
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_quantity] => 8
            [product_name] => Reset
        )
    )
```

I would love to hear some advice, or solutions on how to tackle this!

Comment: A perfect example for the [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) PHP function.

Comment: hi axiac, thanks for the quick response. Haven't heard it before. What would the callback function need to be? Or could you help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal can be reached in many ways. If you aim for speed then use a `foreach` to iterate over the input array, incrementally computing and storing the values into a new array (the body of the callback function below).

If you aim to impress your workmates or a recruiter with your knowledge of PHP then use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$output = array_values(         // We don't need the keys of the generated array
    array_reduce(               // Incrementally process $input using a callback
        $input,
        // $carry is the partial result
        // $item is the currently processed item
        function(array $carry, array $item) {
            // Extract the product name into a local variable
            // we'll use it several times below
            $name = $item['product_name'];
            // If it's a new product then initialize its entry in the output
            if (! array_key_exists($name, $carry)) {
                $carry[$name] = array(
                    'product_quantity' => 0,
                    'product_name'     => $name,
                );
            }
            // Update the quantity of this group
            $carry[$name]['product_quantity'] += $item['product_quantity'];
            // Return the partial result
            return $carry;
        },
        // Start with an empty array
        array()
    )
);
```

#### Update

The OP asked in a comment how to reuse the callback function and make it customizable (*"how do I use a parameter to make `'product_name'` dynamicaly?"*).

You can put the value (`'product_name'`) into a variable (`$key`) outside the function and use the [`use` language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165) to let the anonymous function inherit it.

```
$key = 'product_name';            // The values needs to be in a variable
$output = array_values(
    array_reduce(
        $input,
        // The 'use' keyword lets the anonymous function use a copy of $key
        function(array $carry, array $item) use ($key) {
            $name = $item[$key];
            // The rest of the callback's code comes here unchanged
            // ...
            // Return the partial result
            return $carry;
        },
        array()
    )
);
```

See [Example #3](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165) on the documentation of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) for more examples.

You can store the callback function into a variable. This doesn't improve anything but the readability of the code. However, keep reading, this is just an intermediate step, the real magic happens below.

```
$key = 'abc';
$f = function(array $carry, array $item) use ($key) {
    $name = $item[$key];
    // The rest of the callback's code comes here unchanged
    // ...
    // Return the partial result
    return $carry;
};

$output = array_values(array_reduce($input, $f, array()));
```

To make it really reusable you need to have a way to generate callbacks for different values of `$key`. Let's write a simple function that creates parametrized callbacks:

```
// This function creates a new callback that uses the value of argument $key
function makeFn($key)
{
    return function(array $carry, array $item) use ($key) {
        $name = $item[$key];
        // The rest of the callback's code comes here unchanged
        // ...
        // Return the partial result
        return $carry;
    };
}
```

Now, let's use the new function. It creates different callback functions that can be used to reduce the array by using various keys:

```
$output1 = array_values(array_reduce($input, makeFn('product_name'), array()));
$output2 = array_values(array_reduce($input, makeFn('product_code'), array()));
```

Comment: Awesome man! quick, and working fine! Need to analyse this to use in the future :) Thanks very muchos!

Comment: Hi axiac, quick question about this. I've been using it in different usecases. But how do I use a parameter to make 'product_name' dynamicaly? I want to send a param to the enclosing function that can change the key like so -> 
$name = $item[customParam];

Comment: Put the value into a variable outside the function (`$customParam = 'product_name';`) and use the [`use` language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165) to let the anonymous function inherit it (`function(array $carry, array $item) use ($customParam) { $name = $item[$customParam]; ...}`). See [**Example #3**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165) on the documentation of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: That was what I was looking for! Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not test it, but I think that it can solve your problem.

```
$stocks = [];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    if (isset($stocks[$product['product_name']])) {
        $stocks[$product['product_name']] += $product['product_quantity'];
    } else {
        $stocks[$product['product_name']] = $product['product_quantity'];
    }
}

$finalList = [];

foreach ($stocks as $key => $stock) {
    $finalList[] = [
        'product_quantity' => $stock,
        'product_name' => $key
    ];
}

print_r($finalList);
```

Comment: It should work but why do you use two loops? You can store both name and quantity in `$stocks` in the first `foreach`. It will run twice faster.

Comment: Array
(
    [Appel] => 1
    [D-Day] => 7
    [Emiel] => 10
    [Estella] => 3
    [Feeke] => 5
    [Reset] => 8
)

Then I get this output

Comment: @axiac you are right but it is just fast and dirty version. btw you can do it in the first loop but it will be a bit tricky because you want a sequential array at the end.